# Print list without brackets in a single row

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python
e.g.

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
```

I want to print the array in a single line without the normal " []

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
print (names)
```

Will give the output as;

```
["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
```

That is not the format I want instead I want it to be like this;

```
Sam, Peter, James, Julian, Ann
```

Note: It must be in a single row.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

```
print(', '.join(names))
```

This, like it sounds, just takes all the elements of the list and joins them with `', '`.

Comment: If some elements in `names` aren't strings, use `print(', '.join(map(str,name)))` instead.

Comment: This comment is very useful.

Answer (score 124):

Here is a simple one.

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
print(*names, sep=", ")
```

the star unpacks the list and return every element in the list.

Comment: In `python 2.7.6`, This is a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @FredrickGauss if you add `from __future__ import print_function` it'll work in python 2 as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it also works with non-strings.

Comment: best for strings!

Answer (score 61):

General solution, works on arrays of non-strings:

```
>>> print str(names)[1:-1]
'Sam', 'Peter', 'James', 'Julian', 'Ann'
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the stated requirement. Note the OP's example showing the resulting names without quotes.

Comment: @SteveBennett can you please explain the slicing [1:-1] in your answer. I just started learning python. Thank you.

Comment: `str(names)` generates a string like `['Sam', 'Peter'...'Ann']`. We don't want the square brackets, hence slice from the 2nd character to the second last character.

Comment: Use `str(names)[1:-1].replace("'", "")` to eliminate the quotes.

Answer (score 29):

If the input array is **Integer type** then you need to first convert array into **string type** array and then use `join` method for joining with `,` or **space** whatever you want. e.g:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> print(", " . join(arr))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
>>> sarr = [str(a) for a in arr]
>>> print(", " . join(sarr))
1, 2, 4, 3
>>>
```

Direct using of join which will join the integer and string will throw error as show above.

Answer (score 23):

There are two answers , First is use 'sep' setting

```
>>> print(*names, sep = ', ')
```

The other is below

```
>>> print(', '.join(names))
```

Answer (score 17):

try to use an asterisk before list's name with print statement:

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]  
print(*names)
```

output:

```
Sam Peter James Julian Ann
```

Comment: WOW, this is awesome!

Comment: Is there something similar for printing within a formatted string? `print(f"{*names}")` does not work.

Comment: This is fantastic. Simple and straightforward

Answer (score 12):

This is what you need

```
", ".join(names)
```

Comment: It wraps the result in quotes.

Answer (score 8):

`','.join(list)` will work only if all the items in the list are strings. If you are looking to convert a list of numbers to a comma separated string. such as `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` into `'1,2,3,4'` then you can either

```
str(a)[1:-1] # '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

or

```
str(a).lstrip('[').rstrip(']') # '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

although this won't remove any nested list.

To convert it back to a list

```
a = '1,2,3,4'
import ast
ast.literal_eval('['+a+']')
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

For array of integer type, we need to change it to string type first and than use join function to get clean output without brackets.

```
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
    print(', '.join(map(str, arr)))
```

OUTPUT - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

For array of string type, we need to use join function directly to get clean output without brackets.

```
    arr = ["Ram", "Mohan", "Shyam", "Dilip", "Sohan"]
    print(', '.join(arr)
```

OUTPUT - Ram, Mohan, Shyam, Dilip, Sohan

Answer (score 5):

> print(*names)

this will work in python 3
if you want them to be printed out as space separated.
If you need comma or anything else in between go ahead with .join() solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the list and use `end=" "`to keep it on one line

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
    index=0
    for name in names:
        print(names[index], end=", ")
        index += 1
```

Comment: OP says it must be in a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
print(*name)
```

I found this from [AssemblyAI](https://www.assemblyai.com/) video on youtube, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW-TWrEF6qc&list=WL&index=65&t=112s) part

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33209219)

Comment: `print(*name)` is a self-explanatory answer, and this piece of code does the work for the question. I attached the link only to credit AssemblyAI as I got this solution from their website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is efficient as others but simple logic always works:

```
import sys
name = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    sys.stdout.write(names[i])
    if i != len(names)-1:
        sys.stdout.write(", ")
```

Output:

> Sam, Peter, James, Julian, Ann

Answer (score 0):

The following function will take in a list and return a string of the lists' items.
This can then be used for logging or printing purposes.

```
def listToString(inList):
    outString = ''
    if len(inList)==1:
        outString = outString+str(inList[0])
    if len(inList)>1:
        outString = outString+str(inList[0])
        for items in inList[1:]:
            outString = outString+', '+str(items)
    return outString
```