# Python Strip a list to remove unwanted characters

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a list in my program called student.
I append to this list a string with the name "Reece".
When I print the variable holding my name it outputs:

```
Reece
```

When I print the list which I appended the variable too it outputted:

```
['Reece']
```

How can I like strip it to remove these unwanted characters []'

The code I use is this:

```
name = "Reece"
print name      #Outputs - Reece

student = []
student.append(name)
print student        #Outputs - ["Reece"]
```

If I then appended another thing:

```
Class = "Class A"
student.append(Class)
print student         #Outputs - ["Reece", "Class A"]
```

Comment: impossible to answer without seeing the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python print array without brackets in a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/python-print-array-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce your desired output

```
print student[0]
```

The [ ] are printed because student is a list and [ ] is the list representation.

If you want to print multiple names in a list, you should look at the join method.

It works like this:

```
", ".join(["Reece", "Higgs"])
```

Gives:

```
Reece, Higgs
```

Answer (score 0):

`['Reece']` is the string representation of a list, the square brackets tell you that's what it is, and the quotes mark the start and end of the string in it. A longer list might look like this: `['Reece', 'Andy', 'Geoff']`.

If you'd like to display just one entry, you can refer to its place in the list, counting from zero upwards:

```
print student[0]
```

You might use the list as part of a loop:

```
for person in student:
    print person,
```

The trailing comma removes new lines. If you want each name on a line by itself you can just do `print person`.

It's also possible to make a single string from a list. You can do this with a string and the `join` method.

```
" ".join(student)  # will join all the list entries together with spaces in between
",".join(student)  # will join all the list entries with a comma in between
" hedgehog ".join(student) # will join all the list entries with ' hedgehog ' in between
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format in which you would like the list to be printed.

If you want to print the list separated by spaces, you should convert it to a string, because Python's style of printing lists is **with** the brackets.

```
print ' '.join(list)
```

The `' '` can be replaced with different strings that will join the strings from your list.

If you would like to print a specified element on the list on the other hand, you should use:

```
print list[0]
```

where in place of 0 you can put any number that is in the length range of the list (which means 0 to list length minus 1 as the lists are 0-based).

Finally, to print all the elements from the list, simply use:

```
for element in list:
    print element
```