# How to use ', '.join(var) on integers in Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I've learnt from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/python-print-array-without-brackets-in-a-single-row) that it is possible to join the values in an array using `", ".join(var)` in Python. This code works for strings, for example:

```
var = ["hello","world"]
print (", ".join(var))
```

Gives an output of `hello, world` which is what I want.

However, when I use numbers in the array:

```
var = [1,2,3]
print (", ".join(var))
```

It gives an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print (", ".join(var))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Whereas, I want the output to be:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Is there another way I can this so it will print all of the numbers and also have the ability to be increased so I can have any amount of numbers?

Comment: At the top of my head I think you want: `var = ["1,2,3"]`

Comment: Because `str.join(string iterable) ` , it doesn't take numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert the numbers to strings before `join`ing:

```
var = [1, 2, 3]
print(", ".join(map(str, var)))
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
print(", ".join([str(x) for x in var]))
```

Comment: The list comprehension is not needed, you could directly supply a generator expression: `print(",".join(str(x) for x in var))`

Comment: Map is (ever so slightly) faster, so that's the preferable (while less pythonic) answer if OP is looking for speed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/5388567

Comment: @burnpanck: if you need to iterate over *all* the items, building a list with a list comprehension is usually faster than using a generator (unless the resulting list is very big).

Comment: @eugeney: ... which sounds weird, because you will iterate over each element twice if you use list comprehension. However, it seems to be true nonetheless. A pity, I find solutions that avoid unnecessary intermediates always more elegant.