# Regular expression to extract data from news page

Tags: python, html, regex

Hi I'm running python regular expression to extract some data from news pages, however when it is displayed the code produces brackets and apostrophes in the output. For example this is my code:

```
description_title = findall('<item>[\s]*<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>[\s]*<description>', html_source)[:1]
        news_file.write('<h3 align="Center">' + str(description_title) + ": " + '</h3\n>')
```

but this code creates the output of ['Technology']:, ['Finance']: but i want Technology, Finance without the [''] around it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row

Answer (score 1):

By using [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), you're printing a Python string representation of `description_title` (which is a `list` of length 1).  Try without the `str`:

```
'<h3 align="Center">' + description_title[0] + ": " + '</h3\n>'
```

Comment: If fact, `str` is not defined, in that peculiar case it calls `repr`. Which returns the string representation of a Python `list`.