# How can i adjust my code to remove print desired values only

Tags: python, python-3.x

My current code:

```
def write_from_dict(users_folder):
    for key, value in value_dict.items():  # iterate over the dict
        file_path = os.path.join(users_folder, key + '.txt')
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:       # open the file for writing
            for line in value:                # iterate over the lists

                f.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

My current output:

```
['4802', '156', '4770', '141']
['4895', '157', '4810', '141']
['4923', '156', '4903', '145']
```

My desired output:

```
4802,156,4770,141
4895,157,4810,141
4923,156,4903,145
```

so basically i want the spaces '' and [] removed.

Comment: try changing the last line to: `f.write('{}\n'.format(",".join(map(str, line))))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
f.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

With

```
f.write('{}\n'.format(",".join(line)))
```

Comment: Don't you have to convert those elements to strings?

Comment: Seems like they may be based on the sample output, but they could also be `int`s. OP did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, `line` is a `list` of `ints`, we need to print a string which is the result of concatenating each integer (as strings) togethere with commas.

This can be done really easily with the `str.join` method which takes an iterable of strings and then joins them together with a deliminator - which will be a comma (`','`) here.

So, the `f.write` line should be something like:

```
f.write('{}\n'.format(''.join(str(i) for i in line)))
```

or if the elements of `line` are already strings (it is impossible to tell from your current code), then you can use the more simple:

```
f.write('{}\n'.format(''.join(line)))
```