# How do I get the GUI to print out C and D in the label and not {C and D}? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

On the GUI when the code chooses 'C and D', the output on label looks like {C and D}. Is there a way to get rid of the {} and have it just print out C and D? Preferably without having to add more elements to the list.

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.title('Letters')
def test():
    import random
    letter=['A','B','C and D']
    letterslist=list()
    count = 0
    while count <5:
        y= random.choice(letter)
        letterslist.append(y)
        count=count+1
    return letterslist
x=test()
label1 =Label(root, text = x , fg="White", bg="Orange" )
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `return ''.join(letterlist)` or `return ' '.join(letterlist)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 1):

You could join all the elements of the list with:

```
return ' '.join(letterlist)
```

Your code would look like this now.

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.title('Letters')
def test():
    import random
    letter=['A','B','C and D']
    letterslist=list()
    count = 0
    while count <5:
        y= random.choice(letter)
        letterslist.append(y)
        count=count+1
    return ' '.join(letterslist)
x=test()
label1 =Label(root, text = x , fg="White", bg="Orange" )
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.title('Letters')
def test():
    import random
    letter=['A','B','C and D']
    letterslist=list()
    count = 0
    S=""
    while count <5:
        y= random.choice(letter)
        letterslist.append(y)
        count=count+1
        S=S+str(y)
        if count !=5:
            S=S+","

    print (S, letterslist)
    return S
x=test()
label1 =Label(root, text = x , fg="White", bg="Orange" )
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You can remove the lines with letterslist. I didn't delete them, so that you can compare.