# How to print a list of numbers without square brackets?

Tags: python, list

I'm generating a list of random digits, but I'm struggling to figure out how to output the digits in a single row without the square brackets?

```
import random 
def generateAnswer(answerList):

    listofDigits = []
    while len(listofDigits) < 5:
        digit = random.randint(1, 9)
        if digit not in listofDigits:
            listofDigits.append(digit)
    return listofDigits

def main():
    listofDigits = []
    print(generateAnswer(listofDigits))

main()
```

Comment: Hi, there are a few optimizations you can do. Please check out my answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpack a list and use the `sep` argument:

```
print(*generateAnswer(listofDigits), sep=' ')
```

Comment: that's even better!

Answer (score 4):

```
print(", ".join([str(i) for i in generateAnswer(listofDigits)]))
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
listofDigits = []
print(str(generateAnswer(listofDigits))[1:-1])
```

Also, if `generateAnswer` initialize and return the list, then you don't need to pass in an empty list. Another thing is that if you want to generate a non-repeating random list, you can use `random.sample` and `range`.

I think this is better:

```
import random 
def generateAnswer():
    return random.sample(range(1, 10), 5)

def main():
    print(str(generateAnswer())[1:-1])

main()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: probably the version with the least allocations

Answer (score 1):

The reason you’re getting the brackets is because the `list` class, by default, prints the brackets. To remove the brackets, either use a loop or [string.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> print(' '.join(map(str, listofDigits)))
9 2 1 8 6
>>> for i in listofDigits:
    print(i, end=' ')


9 2 1 8 6
```

Note that the last method adds a space at the end.

Note that in the first method, the arguments need to be cast to strings because you can only `join` strings, not ints.