# remove square brackets from dictionary values output

Tags: python

Hello :) I wrote a little code that creates a dictionary of three people and their favorite numbers.

```
favorite_numbers={"lore":[5, 19], "louise":[7,24],"annie":[1,2]}
```

I'd want an output that prints the name of each person along their favorite numbers

```
for prs, numb in favorite_numbers.items():
    pers= prs
    numb= favorite_numbers[prs]
    print(f"{pers}'s fav numbers are {numb}")
```

this is how i've done it. the thing I dislike, however, is that the numbers appear in square brackets my output ís:

```
lore's fav numbers are [5, 19]
louise's fav numbers are [7, 24]
annie's fav numbers are [1, 2]
```

I'd want it to be:

```
lore's fav numbers are 5, 19
louise's fav numbers are 7, 24
annie's fav numbers are 1, 2
```

so my question is, how should I print my dictionary so that I get rid of the brackets? Thank you in advance

Comment: When using `f""` to print something, whatever you place inside the curly brackets is interpreted. Taking advantage of that and of the fact that `[` and `]` will always be the first and last characters, you can write `{str(numb)[1:-1]}` to have the first and last pieces of the dictionary's string representation removed.

Comment: `numb` is a list, and this is the default way how python prints out lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a list of numbers without square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53111469/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
', '.join(map(str, numb))
```

inside the curly brackets in place of `numb`. This line converts numbers to strings and joins the strings with a comma and space between them.