# How to remove braces and commas from list that is being conjugated with a print line

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
print('Phase 1: Gather user input')
print('--------------------------')

# function to verify the user entered an integer greater than 0
def verifyPositve(x):
    try:
        return int(x) >= 0
    except ValueError:
        return False

print('Please enter integer values, as error-checking has not yet been implemented.')

while True:
    x = input('Enter a positive number: ')
    if verifyPositve(x) == True:
        numList.append(x)
    elif x == 'done':
        break
    else:
        print('You did not pick a positive number.')

print('Numbers entered: %s' % (numList))
```

On the final print statement, I am attempting to include the numbers from the list without the braces or commas.

I found t[his solution on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row) but I can't figure out how to implement it in the same line as "Numbers entered:".

I just keep finding the same solution in searches. Any suggestions or links to a reference on how to solve this?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: This has been solved in the comments with the following code:

```
print('Numbers entered: %s' % ', '.join(numList)))
```

Not sure how to close it or if I just leave it open.

Thank you all.

Comment: How do you want it printed? newlines, spaces, commas?

Comment: `print('Numbers entered: %s' % ', '.join(numList)))` substitute that solution in...

Comment: @Jaba only spaces separating them. My apologies for not adding that.

Comment: @Primusa Worked perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `join()` like in the examples, but convert all the numbers to `str`.

```
numList = [1, 2, 3]

print('Numbers entered: %s' % ' '.join(map(str, numList)))
#Numbers entered: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Edited @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution recommended by Primusa

```
print('Numbers entered: %s' % ', '.join(numList))
```