# Print mixed list without brackets in a single row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in Python.

I have tried to set print(*arr, sep=",") refer "[Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)". But my real problem is:

```
### List
num = 2
arr= [0, "txt", 4, 5, [3,4, num]]
# print full
print(arr)

# print an arr without brackets
print(*arr, sep=",")
```

- Expected result:
  0,txt,4,5,3, 4, 2
- Actual result:
  0,txt,4,5,[3, 4, 2]

The compiler does not remove brackets from sub-list. Please give me advice to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/2988730

Comment: @Raman. There are some significant differences

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to flatten the list first, and then print the new list.

```
def flatten(original, iterables=[list]):
    out = []
    for val in original:
        if type(val) not in iterables:
            out.append(val)
        else:
            out += flatten(val)
    return out


print(flatten(arr))
```

Here I explicitly specify `type(val) != list` so that it will not attempt to split up your strings, but will flatten sub lists. Additionally, this method will handle nested lists of any depth.

Result:

```
>>> print(flatten(arr))
[0, 'txt', 4, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

You can also pass a second argument `iterables`, which is a list containing what iterable types you wish to flatten. This can include `list`, `tuple`, or anything else. Here I default to `list` since that's what your example requires.

Comment: This is cool but what about `str(arr).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace(")",'').replace("(", '')` ?

Comment: Fails on tuples.

Comment: @tpk That is simpler, but will fail if the string elements contain backets

Comment: @DillonDavis Correct!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I assumed that the only iterable that OP wants to flatten are lists based on the example, but I may be interpreting it too literally. In that case, `type(val) not in list_of_iterables_to_flatten` would work.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 updated / generalized my answer with support for other iterables. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: It's exhaustively covered in the duplicate anyway.

Comment: @DillonDavis Thank you very much! It's very useful.

Comment: @AllerwillLee if this solves your problem, feel free to accept it so that others can see that it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this for removing nested bracket only from the list:

```
num = 2    
arr = [0, "txt", 4, 5, [3,4, num]]    
output = []     
def removeBracket(arr): 
    for i in arr: 
        if type(i) == list: 
            removeBracket(i) 
        else: 
            output.append(i)   
removeBracket(arr)
print(output) # [0, 'txt', 4, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```