# Python 3.5: Is there a way to make this list more organized?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say you have the following code:

```
bicycles = ['Trek','Cannondale','Redline','Secialized']
print(bicycles[0],bicycles[1],bicycles[2],bicycles[3])
```

This would print out:

```
Trek Cannondale Redline Specialized
```

I have two questions. **First, Is there a way to make the print string more organized so that you don't have to type out bicycles multiple times?** I know that if you were to just do:

```
print(bicycles)
```

It would print the brackets also, which I'm trying to avoid.

**Second question, how would I insert commas to display within the list when its printed?**

This is how I would like the outcome:

```
Trek, Cannondale, Redline, Specialized.
```

I know that I could just do

```
print("Trek, Cannondale, Redline, Specialized.")
```

But using a list, is there anyway to make it more organzed? Or would printing the sentence out be the smartest way of doing it?

Comment: you can use "for" loop to iterate through each list element and print it out. 
"for bicycle in bicycles: print (bicycle)" will do the job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 7):

> use **.join()** method:
>
> The method `join()` returns a string in which the string elements of
>   sequence have been joined by `str separator`.
>
> *syntax:* `str.join(sequence)`

```
bicycles = ['Trek','Cannondale','Redline','Secialized']
print (' '.join(bicycles))
```

output:

```
Trek Cannondale Redline Secialized
```

Example: change separotor into `', '`:

```
print (', '.join(bicycles))
```

output:

```
Trek, Cannondale, Redline, Secialized
```

> For **python 3.** you can also use **unpacking**:
>
> We can use `*` to unpack the list so that all elements of it can be
>   passed as different parameters.
>
> We use operator `*`

```
bicycles = ['Trek','Cannondale','Redline','Secialized']
print (*bicycles)
```

output:

```
Trek Cannondale Redline Secialized
```

NOTE: 
It's using `' '` as a default separator, or specify one, eg:

```
print(*bicycles, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
Trek, Cannondale, Redline, Secialized
```

It will also work if the elements in the list are different types (without having to explicitly cast to string)

eg, if bicycles was ['test', 1, 'two', 3.5, 'something else']

```
bicycles = ['test', 1, 'two', 3.5, 'something else']
print(*bicycles, sep=', ')
```

output:

```
test, 1, two, 3.5, something else
```

Comment: Since the OP says they're using Python 3.x, then another option is `print(*bicycles)` which'll use `' '` as a default separator, or specify one, eg: `print(*bicycles, sep=', ')`... that'll also work if it's mixed types without having to explicitly cast to string, eg, if `bicycles` was `['test', 1, 'two', 3.5, 'something else']`...

Comment: How would you include a period at the end?

Comment: I hope this isn't taken as a snobby comment, but it would probably also be worth learning how to do this manually as well.
`for y in range(len(bicycles)):
    if y==len(bicycles)-1: end=""
    else: end=","
    print(bicycles[y],end=end)`

Comment: Thank you for nice advice, if you do not mind, I updated my post :) @JackStrosahl

Comment: @sparx like so: `print(*bicycles, sep=', ', end='.')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use join:

```
' '.join(bicycles)

', '.join(bicycles)
```