# Removing numbers and special characters from multi line statement

Tags: regex, python-3.x

With the given input I need to figure out how to get my out put to look as follows. I cannot get rid of the brackets which is my first problem.

```
X= ["This is a hairy #calf",
    "goodbye to the snow #gone",
    "13742 the digits to give",
    "Remember the name d - mayne",
    "I      hate      you"]

Output =
This is hairy calf
goodbye to the snow gone
the digits to give
Remember the name mayne
I hate you
```

This is what I've tried:

```py
X= """["This is an hairy #calf",
    "goodbye to the snow #gone",
    "13742 the digits to give",
    "Remember the name d - mayne",
    "I      hate      you"]"""
X_modified=re.sub(r"[#+-\.\"\n""[""]","",X)
X_modified
```

Comment: Why is `gone` removed but not `calf`? Why is the `d` before the hyphen gone?

Comment: Regarding the quotes and brackets, see [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row).

Comment: I fixed the error. The d is gone because it is a single character by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ast.literal_eval` to cast the string you have into a list, that way you simplify further handling the strings. You may run any kind of replacements on the individual string items  and then join them with a newline.

A [sample snippet](https://ideone.com/yvSBJh):

```
import ast, re
X= """["This is an hairy #calf",
    "goodbye to the snow #gone",
    "13742 the digits to give",
    "Remember the name d - mayne",
    "I      hate      you"]"""
l = ast.literal_eval(X)
rx_non_word = re.compile(r'[^\w\s]+')
rx_white = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')
print ( "\n".join([rx_white.sub(' ', rx_non_word.sub('', x)) for x in l]) ))
```

Output:

```
This is an hairy calf
goodbye to the snow gone
13742 the digits to give
Remember the name d mayne
I hate you
```

The `[^\w\s]+` regex matches 1+ chars other than word and whitespace and `\s{2,}` matches 2 or more whitespaces.

Note you will have to add any exceptions you have to the regex (if any).

Comment: Is there a way to do it just using sub?

Comment: @ronwagner No, I doubt so. At least if you want to achieve the result like in my answer, I think it is not worth even trying to write such a pattern.

Comment: @ronwagner Since there are no other answers I think you will agree that it is the best way.