# How to print a list without brackets and commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print a list without brackets and commas?

```
n1 = 15.3
n2 = 18.2
name = 'Ana'
l = [[name], ['Grade 1: ', round(n1)], ['Grade 2: ', round(n2)]]
print(l)
```

I get:

```
[['Ana'], ['Grade 1: ', 15], ['Grade 2: ', 18]]
```

But I need it like this:

```
Ana 
Grade 1: 15 
Grade 2: 18
```

Comment: Can you try writing a `for` loop to print the elements?

Comment: Don't try to "print the list"; go through the list and find the things that are in it, and print them.

Comment: What did you try that "did not work"? We may be able to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I tried looping and things like   
print(str(nomef)[1:-2])
But now a got help and made it work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of lists, so other questions such as [print list without brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row) don't directly apply.

So loop over the list using `for`, and print each sub-list in turn:

```
for x in l:
    print(*x, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :)

```
n1 = 15.3
n2 = 18.2
name = "Ana"
list = [name, f"Grade 1: {round(n1)}", f"Grade 2: {round(n2)}"]
for thing in list:
    print(f"{thing}")
```

Your problem is that inside a list [] You just need to type the variable or string and a comma afterwards. You don't need to put them in brackets or quotes.

Comment: I tried if the f and {}, to format it, it worked better, but I still got the number with {}, like: {15} {18}.
Then I tried without the list within the list, I removed all the [ ] and it worked
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Print using list comprehension and a star expression `*` to evaluate the list as an iterable.

```
[print(*item) for item in l]
```

The star expression (`*args`)is documented in the Expressions reference:

> If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and expression evaluates to a sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

Comment: List comprehensions are not meant for side effects. i.e. you're creating a list only to print something and left with a list full of `None` that you never use. This case requires a simple loop as already suggested in other answers. List comprehensions are for when you actually need to construct a list

Answer (score -1):

## Little changes

n1 = 15.3

n2 = 18.2

name= 'Ana'

l = [name,'Grade 1: {}'.format(round(n1)),'Grade 1: {}'.format(round(n2))]

## that .format will be useful for you

## added formula:

for things in l:

```
print(things)
```