# How to print integers from a list without brackets or quotes, and without using for loop and no conversion to string?

Tags: python, list

Given the following list:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to  print out the following numbers without brackets,

> 1,2,3,4

without converting them to strings and without using `for` loop.

Is there a way in python to accomplish that?

All my searches lead to either string conversion or generation of another list including brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row) (specifically this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119046/2745495 which should satisfy all your restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(*l1, sep=",")
```

Prints:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: `a = *l1, sep=","
print(type(a)) `  which will make a string, But it is a good solution

Comment: abhi: it must not be a string

Comment: andrej kesely: your code snippet works perfectly if is left untouched, however it presents an invalid syntax error as soon as I apply a small modification. e.g. a=(*l1, sep=","), print(a). Is there a way to assign a variable like I did without running into an error?