# how would I go about getting rid of the square brackets and quote marks when printing a shuffled list

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

```
import random

alphabet = ["R","G","B","Y"]
random.shuffle(alphabet)

code = alphabet[0:3]
```

this is my code and when I print "code" It returns something like this `['B','G','R']`. I want to make it so that it only displays BGR for example.

Comment: `''.join(code)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row, `print(*code)`